# Problema com query em php por causa de aspas

Tags: php, mysql, query

Estou tendo problema com uma query em php da seguinte forma,
Exemplo:

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country)
VALUES ('Cardinal','Tom B. Erichsen','Skagen 21','Stavanger','4006','Norway');
```

Essa query funciona normalmente, porém quando preciso usar alguma palavra que tenha ' no meio causa um problema na query.

Exemplo:

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country)
VALUES ('Cardinal','Tom B. Erichsen','Skagen 21','Stavanger','4006','D'Agua');
```

Essa query ja acontece um erro por causa da palavra D'Agua. Qual o jeito mais simples de resolver isso?
Obs: A query está sendo executada em PHP.

Comment: O recomendado é utilizar [prepared statements](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/91) escapar aspas com barra é uma maneira temporaria.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O ideal, como já mencionado pelo @rray, é usar *prepared statements*.

Mas se for usar *string* "avulsa", já há função certa para isso. Por exemplo, usando funções `mysqli_`:

```
$sql='INSERT INTO Tbl(campo) VALUES ("'.mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn,"D'Agua").'");';
//ou
$sql='INSERT INTO Tbl(campo) VALUES ("'.$mysqli->real_escape_string("D'Agua").'");';
```

Ou em PDO:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO Tbl(campo) VALUES ('. $conn->quote("D'Agua").');';
```

(note que o `quote` já acrescenta aspas na string)

Obsoleto, mas se ainda estiver usando funções `mysql` em aplicações "velhas" (não recomendo):

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO Tbl(campo) VALUES ("'.mysql_escape_string("D'Agua").'");';
```

Veja um exemplo com *prepared statements* com funções `mysqli_`:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO TBL(campo) VALUES (?)');
$stmt->bind_param('s', "D'Agua" );
$stmt->execute();
```

(dá pra fazer em PDO, mas o PDO por padrão só simula *prepared statements*, perdendo justamente suas maiores vantagens. A `mysqli` já faz nativamente)

Answer (score -3):

use a função addslashes().

Exemplo:

```
    $query=addslashes("INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country)
    VALUES ('Cardinal','Tom B. Erichsen','Skagen 21','Stavanger','4006','D'Agua')");
    mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score -3):

Um modo prático, mas não tão bonito seria:

```
$string = "d'agua"
$resultado = str_replace("'","\'",$string);
```

Comment: não sei como fazer para sair barra invertida aqui kkkk não resolveu minha resposta por este motivo

Comment: Isso não é um modo prático, é uma falha de segurança. Se tem isso em algum código, é o caso de corrigir. Do jeito que fez, basta a pessoa por outra barra invertida na string que já desfez a "solução". Exemplo: `string\'abc` vai virar `string\\'abc`, sua barra vai ser anulada pela barra anterior, e o problema das aspas permanece. As bibliotecas da linguagem usada pelo autor da pergunta já tem função apropriada para lidar com isso.