# String replace com aspas simples - php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Olá!

Estou fazendo um insert/update num banco de dados através de um arquivo csv. Estou com problemas quando tento subir o arquivo e ele encontra dado com aspas simples, como por exemplo:  "SANTA BARBARA D'OESTE".

O meu insert ficou:

```
        $sql = mysql_query( 
        "INSERT INTO tabela SET
        `dado1`= '$data[0]',
        `dado2`= '$data[1]',
        `dado3`= '$data[2]'")
```

Ai pensei em fazer um string_replace pra ver se funcionava, com aspas simples não funciona, pois ele entende que é uma aspa aberta:

```
    $dado1= $data[1];
    $dado_alt = str_replace(''','',$dado1);

        //ai o insert ficaria assim:
        "INSERT INTO tabela SET
        `dado1`= '$dado1',
        `dado2`= '$data[1]',
        `dado3`= '$data[2]'")
```

E com aspas duplas também não rolou, até porque a sintaxe é com aspas simples né

```
    $dado1= $data[1];
    $dado_alt = str_replace("'","",$dado1);
```

O que eu posso fazer pra corrigir isso?
Obrigada!!

Comment: Creio que é o mesmo problema, devidamente solucionado: [Problema com query em php por causa de aspas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/122077/70)

Comment: Como não teve mais nenhuma atividade na postagem, fechei como duplicata. Entendo que a solução está no link indicado, mas se tiver alguma dúvida, deixe um comentário que tentaremos ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

O php aceita tanto aspas duplas como aspas simples para uma string. No seu caso não vai funcionar com aspas simples, porque o compilador vai interpretar que você esta abrindo mais uma aspas.

A diferença entre aspas duplas e simples:

Aspas duplas: `"{$data[1]}"` ou `"$dado_alt";` // aceita printa pela variável

Aspas simples: `'apenas string';` // aceita apenas a string

Já sobre a sintaxe, ela esta correta. Copie esse trecho de código e utilize esse site para executar (http://phpfiddle.org/).

```
$string  = "SANTA BARBARA D'OESTE";
<br>
$dado_alt = str_replace("'","",$string);
<br>
echo $dado_alt;
```

Na minha opinião ao invés de remover, você poderia colocar um caractere especial para mais tarde poder tratar esse valor. Assim mostraria o valor real.